# Win32 Stream Handles - Changing To Binary Mode

Tags: c, winapi, pipe

I'm using [CreatePipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create handles that I then pass on when launching a child process.

The child process writes binary information to its standard out, which is redirected into the pipe I've created.

However, when it comes to writing the number '10', things go haywire and I get too many characters of output - I'm assuming this is because the stream is open in text mode and it's automatically adding a 13.

Is there any way in Win32 that I can take the HANDLE returned from CreatePipe and change the stream mode to binary, the same way I could with the function _setmode, if I had a FILE*? Or is there a way to translate he handle into a FILE* so I can use _setmode?

**Sample Code:**

```
HANDLE hOutputReadTmp,hInputWriteTmp;

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;

bool Binary = true;

// Set up the security attributes struct.
sa.nLength= sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

if (!CreatePipe(&hInputRead,&hInputWriteTmp,&sa,0))
{
    Error = "Unable to Create Input Pipe";
    return false;
};

if (Binary == true) 
{
    //Put a magic something here to change the hInputRead stream to Binary.
    //_setmode(_fileno(hInputRead,_O_BINARY);
}
```

***EDIT***

This is probably more to do with the CHILD PROCESS writing to stdout as a text stream. Give me a minute to take a look at this and I might come back and delete this whole post!

Comment: Can you also post the child process code that makes it explode?

Comment: Win32 APIs don't do any text-mode translations.

How are you reading from the pipe?

Comment: Yeah - it just occured to me that it's probably the CHILD process that is writing to the stream as if its text-based (I'm using simple cout.write calls).

Comment: Using cout calls would definitely explain it.